# How to change dataBinding support-compat api version?

Tags: java, android

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 25.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.4.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samplename"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding.enabled = true

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
}
```

I get above warning after dataBinding.enabled = true. I do not want to use api 26. how to reduce dataBinding support-compat api to 25 or any other api?

Comment: Bear in mind that you will not be able to ship this app on the Play Store, or update it, starting in a few months, due to your low `targetSdkVersion`. I recommend that you move to use 27 for all of the relevant versions (`compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and the major version of the support libraries). However, there are Gradle recipes for forcing the use of older dependency versions, and you would need to use those to force older versions of the dependencies that data binding is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
I use lower version of gradle. com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 in my case.